# I have problems in paging List and advance search

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a problem, I use Paging  and it works without filtering  with a simple filter  but when data comes from an advance search, I get below error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[WomenNew.Models.News_]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'PagedList.IPagedList'1[WomenNew.Models.News_]'.

If I can create my advance search without sql string and stored procedure (I explain i bellow code)  my problem will be resolved  or if I can convert my `object List<News_>`  it will be fine and my changes will be little

My controller advance search is:

```
public ActionResult AdvanceSearch_(string DateSFrom, string DateSTo, string Export, string Media, string issue, string subject, string society, string official, string details, string details2, string details3)
{
    // create object 
    List < News_ > newsList_ = new List<News_>();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(details))
    {
        strQuery2 = "(Details like N'%" + details + "%')";
    }
    // here other parameter of search is created:
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Media))
    {
        strQuery2 += "(Media  like N'%" + CommonClass.Cpersian(Media) + "%')";
    }
    // here deferment parameters are joint
    strQuery2 = strQuery2.Replace(")(", ") and (");
    //here with a stored procedure method object is filled
    newsList_ = cmd.GetNewsList(strQuery);
    if (newsList_.Count > 0)
    {
        TempData["news_List"] = newsList_;
        if (Export == "Search")
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "News_");

        else
       .........
```

Here is Index action if TempData["news_List"] is not null the object pass to Index view [HttpGet] If I could create different parameters in Index like this code:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(string searchBy, string search, int? page)
{
    if (TempData["news_List"] != null)
    {
        return View(TempData["news_List"]);
    }

    if (searchBy == "News")
    {
        return View(db.News_.Where(x => (x.Details.Contains(search)) ||
            (x.Issue.Contains(search))).OrderByDescending(s => s.Id).ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1,3));
```

but in advance action I don't know how can I create .... `x => (x.Details.....`

or how can i pass to index view

My object in view is :

```
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@model IPagedList<WomenNew.Models.News_>
```

I prefer  to convert  to convert `List< News_> newsList_ = new List<News_>();`  to `IPagedList` otherwise I have to change my advance search but if it is necessary  i'll do.

Comment: You need to convert `TempData["news_List"];` to `IPagedList<News_>` before you return the view

Comment: I tried but I can't newsList_ is the object that copied to TempData["news_List"], first according to your way, I wrote: IPagedList<News_> list = newsList_. so it 's converted to IpagedList ||| and then i wrote TempData["news_List"] = list; but it's not converted and  it get error that says : List<News_> does not contain a definition for 'TemplData' and no extension method 'TempData' accepting a first argument of type 'List<News_>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) what should i do? thanks. Tomas – tomas 1 hour ago

Comment: You need to cast it. `if (TempData["news_List"] != null) { var list = TempData["news_List"] as List<News_>; return View(list.ToPagedList(page ?? 1,3)); }`

Comment: Hi  Stephen,
Thank you so much , I really appreciate  your guide  you saved a lot of time for me and  how can I mark your  answer as best because you sent a comment
Best regards,
Tomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stephen Muecke sent me the correct answer, he wrote me :

You need to convert TempData["news_List"]; to IPagedList before you return the view you need to change the ActionIndex as below:
        if (TempData["news_List"] != null) 
        { var list = TempData["news_List"] as List;
         return View(list.ToPagedList(page ?? 1,3)); 
        .....}
I appreciate Stephen Muecke It saved me a lot of time. Tomas

shareeditdeleteflag